# javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

I created dynamic project by using Eclipse. In this project , I have added the hibernate Configuration for mysql database. I am using the servlet for crud operations. I know in maven project the required dependency can be added but not for web applications. I have added the Java.persistance jar files into lib folder. Here is the project structure.[image].

Here is the Hibernate code.

```
package net.javaguides.usermanagement.utl;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Environment;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

import net.javaguides.usermanagement.model.User;

/**
 * Java based configuration
 * @author ramesh Fadatare
 *
 */
public class HibernateUtil {
 private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

 public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
  if (sessionFactory == null) {
   try {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    // Hibernate settings equivalent to hibernate.cfg.xml's properties
    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.put(Environment.DRIVER, "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    settings.put(Environment.URL, "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?useSSL=false");
    settings.put(Environment.USER, "root");
    settings.put(Environment.PASS, "");
    settings.put(Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");

    settings.put(Environment.SHOW_SQL, "true");

    settings.put(Environment.CURRENT_SESSION_CONTEXT_CLASS, "thread");

    settings.put(Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "create-drop");

    configuration.setProperties(settings);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
      .applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
    System.out.println("Hibernate Java Config serviceRegistry created");
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    return sessionFactory;

   } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }
  return sessionFactory;
 }
}
```

Here is the servlet.

```
package net.javaguides.usermanagement.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import net.javaguides.usermanagement.dao.UserDao;
import net.javaguides.usermanagement.model.User;

/**
 * ControllerServlet.java
 * This servlet acts as a page controller for the application, handling all
 * requests from the user.
 * @email Ramesh Fadatare
 */

@WebServlet("/")
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private UserDao userDao;

    public void init() {
        userDao = new UserDao();
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getServletPath();

        try {
            switch (action) {
                case "/new":
                    showNewForm(request, response);
                    break;
                case "/insert":
                    insertUser(request, response);
                    break;
                case "/delete":
                    deleteUser(request, response);
                    break;
                case "/edit":
                    showEditForm(request, response);
                    break;
                case "/update":
                    updateUser(request, response);
                    break;
                default:
                    listUser(request, response);
                    break;
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            throw new ServletException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void listUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws SQLException, IOException, ServletException {
        List < User > listUser = userDao.getAllUser();
        request.setAttribute("listUser", listUser);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-list.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void showNewForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private void showEditForm(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws SQLException, ServletException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        User existingUser = userDao.getUser(id);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("user-form.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("user", existingUser);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);

    }

    private void insertUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws SQLException, IOException {
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        User newUser = new User(name, email, country);
        userDao.saveUser(newUser);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    private void updateUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws SQLException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String country = request.getParameter("country");

        User user = new User(id, name, email, country);
        userDao.updateUser(user);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }

    private void deleteUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws SQLException, IOException {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"));
        userDao.deleteUser(id);
        response.sendRedirect("list");
    }
}
```

Here is the result when I run the applications.

[image]

Comment: No. How to.invoked the depency for javax for dynamic web project?

Comment: By including the JAXB API library (and an implementation library) in your application. I don't see them in your screenshot. This is what the linked-to question covers. Let me know if I have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Thanks very much . Yes you are right . problem was this files work fine with Eclipse and java older versions but not for newer versions.The additional jar file must be added. Problem solve. Thanks you very much.

Comment: `javax` classes are not included in the JRE anymore in modern versions of java . You need to bring them yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @andrewjames pointed out, you need to download the JAXB-API library and an implementation, they are required by Hibernate.

Although you do not use Maven for dependency management, you can download the corresponding artifacts by clicking in the `jar` link that you can find in the `Files` row in the HTML table presented in the artifact page.

You need to download:

- The [JAXB-API](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/xml/bind/jaxb-api/2.3.1/jaxb-api-2.3.1.jar)
- A [JAXB Runtime](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.3.1/jaxb-runtime-2.3.1.jar), for instance, the reference implementation from Glassfish.

You already have [javax.activation](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar) in your dependencies. It is required by JAXB-API.

Comment: I would also add that it would be better for the OP to start using a dependency management tool such as Maven or Gradle - it will almost certainly pay dividends - especially when it comes to managing dependencies (and dependencies of dependencies...) in a reliable, automated way.

Comment: Thank for suggestions will keep in mind

Comment: I totally agree with you @andrewjames